# Getting unexpected input request

Tags: c

I am a beginner and I am learning the C programming language. I am trying to code a program that multiplies two matrices.

I am taking two inputs. The first is for the row and the second is for the column. The rows and columns of the two matrices will be the same. So I am taking row and column input only for one time.

For the first matrix, the input is working properly. But for the second matrix, it is taking more input than the first input. In my test case, the number of rows was 2 and the number of columns was 3.

My C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matrixInput(int matrix[][10], int row, int column, int matrixNo) {
  printf("Matrix %d input:\n", matrixNo);

  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      printf("Matrix %d [%d, %d]: ", matrixNo, i + 1, j + 1);
      scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
}

void matrixDisplay(int matrix[][10], int row, int column, int matrixNo) {
  printf("Matrix %d output:\n", matrixNo);

  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  int row, column;

  printf("Row: ");
  scanf("%d", &row);
  printf("Column: ");
  scanf("%d", &column);

  int matrix1[row][column], matrix2[row][column];

  matrixInput(matrix1, row, column, 1);
  matrixInput(matrix2, row, column, 2);
  
  matrixDisplay(matrix1, row, column, 1);
  matrixDisplay(matrix2, row, column, 2);

  return 0;
}
```

When I am using `void matrixInput(int matrix[row][column], int row, int column, int matrixNo)`, I am getting these errors:

```
error: 'row' undeclared here (not in a function)
error: 'column' undeclared here (not in a function)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. "*How can I solve this problem?"* So what is "this problem"? The incorrect input or the compile time error? Also, for the incorrect input please give the exact run log to make it clear what "taking more input" means.

Comment: I think `int matrix1[row][column], matrix2[row][column];`, this memory is allocated during build process and so `row` and `column` has the garbage values or unknown. You'll have to dynamically allocate the memory for `matrix1` and `matrix2`.

Comment: Note that if you have two matrices of size NxM, you can only multiply them if N equals M.  In general, you can multiply an NxM matrix by an MxP matrix; the number of columns in the first matrix must match the number of rows in the second.

Comment: @shubham That's not correct. The OP is using [Variable Length Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA) which is a c99 feature (and optionally supported in C11).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `int matrix[][10]` of the functions `matrixInput` and `matrixDisplay` is wrong. You should not use an arbitrary size, instead it should be equal to `column`.

Therefore, you should change

`int matrix[][10]`

to

`int matrix[][column]`

in both function prototypes.

However, you can only do this after declaring `column`. Therefore, you must also change the order of the parameters. For example, you could change

`void matrixInput(int matrix[][10], int row, int column, int matrixNo)`

to

`void matrixInput(int row, int column, int matrix[][column], int matrixNo)`

and change the function calls accordingly.

Comment: After changing to `void matrixInput(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo)` the function is taking input only for 1 time.

Comment: @SatyajitRoy: Did you also change the function call of `maxtrixInput` in `main`, to reflect the change in the order of the parameters?

Answer (score 4):

You have function signatures:

```c
void matrixInput(int matrix[][10], int row, int column, int matrixNo);
void matrixDisplay(int matrix[][10], int row, int column, int matrixNo);
```

but the arrays you are passing to the functions do not have 10 columns.

You should make the dimensions match:

```c
void matrixInput(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo);
void matrixDisplay(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols], int matrixNo);
```

I've renamed the size variables and placed them before they are used — using C99 variable-length array (VLA) notation.  Renaming them is optional; defining the sizes before they are used in the array definition is mandatory.  Obviously, you must also fix your function calls.

You could replace the `[rows]` subscript in the function definition/declaration with `[]`, but I regard it as clearer to specify both dimensions.

The extra input requested probably arises because you've invoked *undefined behaviour* because the array sizes don't match.  The chances are that the first input has overwritten some of the key data.  You could try printing `rows` and `cols` (or `row` and `column` in your naming convention) on entry to (and maybe exit from) the `matrixInput()` function.  Doing so would probably show you that there is a problem.  There isn't much point in working out what's going on in detail; undefined behaviour is erratic and can vary between compilers or releases of a single compiler (or even between compilations by the same compiler — though that would be unusual in practice).  You could also consider printing the first array after entering it; you might be surprised by what you see in the output.  Fix the problem by making the sizes match.